# GNU/R 'no audio drivers are available'

Tags: audio, r

Error message as in title shows up in console when trying to execute play() function from audio package. I found plenty of references to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490982/rbeepr-error-in-beepr-package-in-r) question, but link provided in the answer is dead. How to load a driver into R in Ubuntu?

edit:

I can play audio without any problems outside R. I am using Xubuntu 15.10. This code generates an error:

```
> library(audio);
> s<-load.wave("audio.wav");
> play(s)
```

edit2:

R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"

Error message I get:

```
Error in 'play.default(x, rate, ...)':no audio drivers are available
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please also show the specific error message you get. Your version of R might also be relevant (I doubt it, but you never know).

Comment: Requested information added in original question.